# Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?

Tags: reactjs

I have an external (to the component), observable object that I want to listen for changes on. When the object is updated it emits change events, and then I want to rerender the component when any change is detected.

With a top-level `React.render` this has been possible, but within a component it doesn't work (which makes some sense since the `render` method just returns an object).

Here's a code example:

```js
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  handleButtonClick() {
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Math.random()}
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick.bind(this)}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Clicking the button internally calls `this.render()`, but that's not what actually causes the rendering to happen (you can see this in action because the text created by `{Math.random()}` doesn't change). However, if I simply call `this.setState()` instead of `this.render()`, it works fine.

**So I guess my question is:** do React components *need* to have state in order to rerender? Is there a way to force the component to update on demand without changing the state?

Comment: the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30626072/3151337) says `this.forceUpdate()` is the right solution whereas rest of all answers and several comments are against using `forceUpdate()`. Will that then be fine to say that the question didn't get a proper solution/answer yet?

Comment: The excepted answer answered my question at the time. Is is technically the answer I was looking for, and I still think the right answer. The other answers I think are good supplemental information for folks with the same question to be aware of.

Comment: Interesting to note is that you DON'T NEED ANYTHING IN STATE at all other than initializing it to a plain object, then calling this.setState({}) just triggers a new render. React is great but also weird sometimes. Therefore you could directly loop through a stores data when trigger a change without extra plumbing or worry about data per component instance.

Comment: On the whole I would say yes. If you are using force update this is for updating components where they may be dependent on changes outside  of the state management of your app. I cannot think of a good example of that. Useful to know though.

Comment: Why would you even need to do this? -- it's wrong logic in your app!!!!

Answer (score 1056, accepted):

In class components, you can call `this.forceUpdate()` to force a rerender.

Documentation: [https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)

In function components, there's no equivalent of `forceUpdate`, but you can [contrive a way to force updates with the `useState` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837442/200224).

Comment: Another way is this.setState(this.state);

Comment: Using forceupdate is discouraged, please see the last answer.

Comment: While `this.forceUpdate()` isn't a very good solution to the askers' problem, it's the correct answer to the question posed in the title. While it should generally be avoided, there are situations when forceUpdate is a good solution.

Comment: @kar Actually, additional logic can be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()` rendering your solution futile.

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Error: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
_this2.forceUpdate is not a function

Comment: @zulkarnainshah a stateless functional component does not have 'this' attached.

If you want to use forceUpdate, then you'll need to turn your component into a class.

Comment: `setState()` is asynchronous. And that's why in some cases it doesn't work very well.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell No, there are certain cases where `forceUpdate()` is useful. If it were really so bad, it wouldn't be part of the API in the first place.

Answer (score 438):

`forceUpdate` should be avoided because it deviates from a React mindset. The React docs cite an example of when `forceUpdate` might be used:

> By default, when your component's state or props change, your component will re-render. However, if these change implicitly (eg: data deep within an object changes without changing the object itself) or if your render() method depends on some other data, you can tell React that it needs to re-run render() by calling forceUpdate().

However, I'd like to propose the idea that even with deeply nested objects, `forceUpdate` is unnecessary. By using an immutable data source tracking changes becomes cheap; a change will always result in a new object so we only need to check if the reference to the object has changed. You can use the library [Immutable JS](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to implement immutable data objects into your app.

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your component "pure" and your application much simpler and more efficient.[forceUpdate()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate)

Changing the key of the element you want re-rendered will work. Set the key prop on your element via state and then when you want to update set state to have a new key.

```
<Element key={this.state.key} />
```

Then a change occurs and you reset the key

```
this.setState({ key: Math.random() });
```

I want to note that this will replace the element that the key is changing on. An example of where this could be useful is when you have a file input field that you would like to reset after an image upload.

While the true answer to the OP's question would be `forceUpdate()` I have found this solution helpful in different situations. I also want to note that if you find yourself using `forceUpdate` you may want to review your code and see if there is another way to do things.

**NOTE 1-9-2019:**

The above (changing the key) will completely replace the element. If you find yourself updating the key to make changes happen you probably have an issue somewhere else in your code. Using `Math.random()` in key will re-create the element with each render. I would NOT recommend updating the key like this as react uses the key to determine the best way to re-render things.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this got a downvote?  I've been banging my head trying to get screen readers to respond to aria alerts and this is the only technique I've found that works reliably.  If you have something in your UI that generates the same alert each time it is clicked, by default react doesn't re-render the DOM so the screen reader doesn't announce the change. Setting a unique key makes it work. Maybe the downvote was because it still involves setting state.  But forcing a re-render to DOM by setting key is golden!

Comment: I very much liked this answer because - 1: use of forceupdate() is discouraged, and 2: this way is very helpful for 3rd party components which you have installed via npm, meaning not your own components. E.g React-resizable-and-movable is a 3rd party component that I use, but it's not reacting to my component setstate. this is great solution.

Comment: Won't changing a key remove old html nodes and create new ones?

Comment: Moreover, additional logic can be implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()` rendering your solution futile.

Comment: @Qwerty `key` allows for reordering nodes for speed (skipping remove/add), but AFAIK if there's no candidate it'll change the existing node instead of doing a complete remove/add

Comment: @Qwerty But yes, using `key` isn't good for this example, since OP was just outputting the value, not doing anything fancy like that

Comment: This is a hack and an abuse of `key`. First, it's intent is unclear. A reader of your code will have to work hard to understand why you are using `key` this way. Second, this is no more pure than `forceUpdate`. "Pure" React means that the visual presentation of your component is 100% dependent on its state, so if you change any state, it updates. If however, you have some deeply nested objects (the scenario the `forceUpdate` docs cite a reason to use it) then using `forceUpdate` makes that clear. Third, `Math.random()` is…random. Theoretically, it could generate the same random number.

Comment: @xtraSimplicity I can't agree that this complies with the React way of doing things. `forceUpdate` is the React way of doing this.

Comment: @Robert Grant, looking back, I agree. The added complexity isn't really worth it.

Comment: It is a useful solution in certain cases, especially if you can tie key uniquely to the data. I rarely have to use this stuff outside of things like charts (which compose with a lot of deeply nested elements), but it's useful when I need to do so—e.g. not Math.random() but key tied to a unique index for the data that forces a rerender.

Comment: Its been some time since I answered this question. The only case in which I've needed to randomize the key lately was using the beta react hot module loader, but it was more of a hack than anything. The immutable part of this answer holds true. Your components should react to updates to your data. I've found most of the time when using redux I can eliminate state all together and use pure components that will be updated when the data in their props change. And that data is passed as props by using the `connect` function from the `react-redux` package.

Comment: I would like to add a practical usecase in which I think forceUpdate is okay, but please correct me if I missed any options:
I have a container which needs to perform an update on itself (translate style) after all child nodes have been mounted and interrogated for their width (which is set via stylesheet and outside of my control). In this case, this.setState(this.state); would not be idiomatic as nothing in the state has changed and I only require to re-run render(). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @bpylearner I think passing in the translate values as props or using the components state for the translate values would be a better way to do it, but if you are translating a value via css - i don't see why you would need to use forceUpdate

Comment: @realseanp That was an option I had considered, but the translate value is a something I don't want the rest of the app to be concerned with. Instead the app passes in the item to be focused, the component renders, interrogates all its refs to calculate the proper offsets, and then forces a re-render to update to the correct position. The child dimensions (to my last tests), are only available after render has already run. Since no state has changed to the rest of the app, I thought forceUpdate would be more idiomatic not to use this.setState(...) method.

Comment: @atomkirk I was of the same opinion as you, however, surprisingly react docs approve and even recommend this method in some cases: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: math.random() does create issue in safari.

Comment: I was going to upvote for the changing the key suggestion - brilliant - until I saw the editorial. A VERY good legitimate reason to force an update is when you have an entrance animation. I'm sure there are others.

Comment: @PeterMoore yeah another reason may be when you want to re-render a component thus ensuring all life cycle methods/hooks run from a fresh state.

Comment: yeah just make sure your redux assets' reference objects are using spread to create a new reference. redux/react doesn't always notice an updated object/array w the same reference. your components local state should be fine as state objects are immutable (non changeable, they are created new each time by react using setState in class or hooks in functional) but if you have a saga or action updating state, create a new reference with spread. this will probably fix som of OP's issues related to state.

Answer (score 189):

In 2021 and 2022, this is [the official way](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate) to forceUpdate a React Functional Component.

```
const [, forceUpdate] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);

  function handleClick() {
    forceUpdate();
  }
```

I know the OP is for a class component. But the question was asked in 2015 and now that hooks are available, many may search for `forceUpdate` in functional components. This little bit is for them.

**Edit 18th Apr 2022**

It's usually bad practice to force update your components.

A few reasons that can cause the need to use force updates.

- Not using state variables where you have to - local, redux, context.
- The field from the state object you are trying to access and expecting to update/change is too deeply nested in objects or arrays. Even Redux advises to maintain flat objects or arrays. If only one field value changes in a complex object, React may not figure out that the state object has changed, thus it does not update the component. Keep your state flat and simple.
- The key on your list items, as mentioned in another answer. In fact, this can cause other unexpected behaviors as well. I've seen lists where items are repeatedly rendered (duplicates) because the keys aren't identical or the keys are just missing altogether. Always request the backend team to send unique ids everywhere possible! Avoid using array indexes for keys. Do not try to create unique ids on the front-end by using nanoid, uuid or random. Because ids created using above methods change each time the component updates (keys provided to a list need to be static and the same on each render). Creating unique ids is usually a backend concern. Try your best to not bring that requirement to the front-end. The front-end's responsibility is only to paint what data the backend returns and not create data on the fly.
- If your useEffect, useCallback dependency arrays do not have the proper values set. Use ESLint to help you with this one! Also, this is one of the biggest causes for memory leaks in React. Clean up your state and event listeners in the return callback to avoid memory leaks. Because such memory leaks are awfully difficult to debug.
- Always keep an eye on the console. It's your best friend at work. Solving warning and errors that show up in the console can fix a whole lot of nasty things - bugs and issues that you aren't even aware off.

A few things I can remember that I did wrong. In case it helps..

Comment: Keep in mind that it still says: "Try to avoid this pattern if possible".

Comment: @John Yep, that's the case for all the answers to this question because you aren't supposed to `forceUpdate`. If you find yourself using any of the implementations of a forced update, it usually means you are doing something that is not the React way. Avoid forceUpdate as much as possible, unless you have to!

Answer (score 119):

Actually, `forceUpdate()` is the only correct solution as `setState()` might **not** trigger a re-render if additional logic is implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()` or when it simply returns `false`.

#### forceUpdate()

> Calling `forceUpdate()` will cause `render()` to be called on the component, skipping `shouldComponentUpdate()`. *[more...](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate)*

#### setState()

> `setState()` will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in `shouldComponentUpdate()`. *[more...](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)*

---

`forceUpdate()` can be called from within your component by `this.forceUpdate()`

---

### Hooks: [How can I force component to re-render with hooks in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215285/how-can-i-force-component-to-re-render-with-hooks-in-react/58606536#58606536)

---

#### BTW: Are you mutating state or your nested properties don't propagate?

- [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149659/985454)
- [Sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react/50149659?noredirect=1#comment109484301_50149659)

Comment: one interesting thing to note is that state assingments outside of setState such as this.state.foo = 'bar' will not trigger the render lifecycle method

Comment: @lfender6445 Assigning state directly with `this.state` outside of the constructor should also throw an error. Might not have done so in 2016; but, I am pretty sure it does it now.

Answer (score 52):

### I Avoided `forceUpdate` by doing following

> **WRONG WAY** : do not use index as key

```
this.state.rows.map((item, index) =>
   <MyComponent cell={item} key={index} />
)
```

> **CORRECT WAY** : Use data id as key, it can be some guid etc

```
this.state.rows.map((item) =>
   <MyComponent item={item} key={item.id} />
)
```

so by doing such code improvement your component will be **UNIQUE** and render naturally

Comment: ```this.state.rows.map((item) =>
   <MyComponent item={item} key={item.id} />
)```

Comment: To justify my down vote, despite it is a good practice to use this approach, this answer is not related to the question.

Answer (score 42):

When you want two React components to communicate, which are not bound by a relationship (parent-child), it is advisable to use [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/) or similar architectures.

What you want to do is to listen for changes of the <strike>observable component</strike> store, which holds the model and its interface, and saving the data that causes the render to change as `state` in `MyComponent`. When the store pushes the new data, you change the state of your component, which automatically triggers the render.

Normally you should try to avoid using `forceUpdate()` . From the documentation:

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from this.props and this.state in render(). This makes your application much simpler and more efficient

Comment: What is the memory status of a component state? If I have five components on a page and they all are listening to a single store, do I have the data five times in memory, or are they references? And don't all of those listeners add up fast? Why is it better to "trickle down" than to just pass data to your target?

Comment: Actually the recommendations are to pass the store data to component props and only use the component state for things like scroll state and other minor ui-specific things. If you use [redux](https://npmjs.org/package/redux) (I recommend it), you can use the [connect](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) function from `react-redux` to automatically map store state to component props whenever needed based on a mapping function you supply.

Comment: @AJFarkas the state would be assigned to a store's data which is just a pointer to it anyway so memory is not an issue unless you are cloning.

Comment: "forceUpdate() should be always avoided" is incorrect.  The documentation clearly says:  "Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate()".  There are valid use cases of `forceUpdate`

Comment: @AJP you're absolutely right, that was personal bias speaking :) I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 25):

## use hooks or HOC take your pick

Using **hooks** or the **HOC (higher order component) pattern**, you can have automatic updates when your stores change. This is a very light-weight approach without a framework.

**useStore** Hooks way to handle store updates

```
interface ISimpleStore {
  on: (ev: string, fn: () => void) => void;
  off: (ev: string, fn: () => void) => void;
}

export default function useStore<T extends ISimpleStore>(store: T) {
  const [storeState, setStoreState] = useState({store});
  useEffect(() => {
    const onChange = () => {
      setStoreState({store});
    }
    store.on('change', onChange);
    return () => {
      store.off('change', onChange);
    }
  }, []);
  return storeState.store;
}
```

**withStores** HOC handle store updates

```
export default function (...stores: SimpleStore[]) {
  return function (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<any>) {
    return class WithStore extends PureComponent<{}, {lastUpdated: number}> {
      constructor(props: React.ComponentProps<any>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          lastUpdated: Date.now(),
        };
        this.stores = stores;
      }

      private stores?: SimpleStore[];

      private onChange = () => {
        this.setState({lastUpdated: Date.now()});
      };

      componentDidMount = () => {
        this.stores &&
          this.stores.forEach((store) => {
            // each store has a common change event to subscribe to
            store.on('change', this.onChange);
          });
      };

      componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this.stores &&
          this.stores.forEach((store) => {
            store.off('change', this.onChange);
          });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <WrappedComponent
            lastUpdated={this.state.lastUpdated}
            {...this.props}
          />
        );
      }
    };
  };
}
```

**SimpleStore class**

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import ee, {Emitter} from 'event-emitter';

interface SimpleStoreArgs {
  key?: string;
  defaultState?: {[key: string]: any};
}

export default class SimpleStore {
  constructor({key, defaultState}: SimpleStoreArgs) {
    if (key) {
      this.key = key;
      // hydrate here if you want w/ localState or AsyncStorage
    }
    if (defaultState) {
      this._state = {...defaultState, loaded: false};
    } else {
      this._state = {loaded: true};
    }
  }
  protected key: string = '';
  protected _state: {[key: string]: any} = {};
  protected eventEmitter: Emitter = ee({});
  public setState(newState: {[key: string]: any}) {
    this._state = {...this._state, ...newState};
    this.eventEmitter.emit('change');
    if (this.key) {
      // store on client w/ localState or AsyncStorage
    }
  }
  public get state() {
    return this._state;
  }
  public on(ev: string, fn:() => void) {
    this.eventEmitter.on(ev, fn);
  }
  public off(ev: string, fn:() => void) {
    this.eventEmitter.off(ev, fn);
  }
  public get loaded(): boolean {
    return !!this._state.loaded;
  }
}
```

**How to Use**

In the case of hooks:

```
// use inside function like so
const someState = useStore(myStore);
someState.myProp = 'something';
```

In the case of HOC:

```
// inside your code get/set your store and stuff just updates
const val = myStore.myProp;
myOtherStore.myProp = 'something';
```

```
// return your wrapped component like so
export default withStores(myStore)(MyComponent);
```

**MAKE SURE**
To export your stores as a singleton to get the benefit of global change like so:

```
class MyStore extends SimpleStore {
  public get someProp() {
    return this._state.someProp || '';
  }
  public set someProp(value: string) {
    this.setState({...this._state, someProp: value});
  }
}
// this is a singleton
const myStore = new MyStore();
export {myStore};
```

This approach is pretty simple and works for me. I also work in large teams and use Redux and MobX and find those to be good as well but just a lot of boilerplate. I just personally like my own approach because I always hated a lot of code for something that can be simple when you need it to be.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your Store class example in the update method having to write the first line of the method as following: `this._data = {...this._data, ...newData}`.

Comment: React discourages inheritance in favor of composition. https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Just wondering about clarity/readibility, how coud this.setState(this.state) be better than this.forceUpdate()?

Answer (score 22):

> So I guess my question is: do React components need to have state in
>   order to rerender? Is there a way to force the component to update on
>   demand without changing the state?

The other answers have tried to illustrate how you could, but the point is that *you shouldn't*. Even the hacky solution of changing the key misses the point. The power of React is giving up control of manually managing when something should render, and instead just concerning yourself with how something should map on inputs. Then supply stream of inputs.

If you need to manually force re-render, you're almost certainly not doing something right.

Answer (score 13):

For completeness, you can also achieve this in functional components:

```
const [, updateState] = useState();
const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
// ...
forceUpdate();
```

Or, as a reusable hook:

```
const useForceUpdate = () => {
  const [, updateState] = useState();
  return useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);
}
// const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53215514/2692307

Please note that using a force-update mechanism is still bad practice as it goes against the react mentality, so it should still be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few ways to rerender your component:

The simplest solution is to use forceUpdate() method:

```
this.forceUpdate()
```

One more solution is to create not used key in the state(nonUsedKey)
 and call setState function with update of this nonUsedKey:

```
this.setState({ nonUsedKey: Date.now() } );
```

Or rewrite all current state:

```
this.setState(this.state);
```

Props changing also provides component rerender.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it a couple of ways:

**1. Use the `forceUpdate()` method:**

There are some glitches that may happen when using the `forceUpdate()` method. One example is that it ignores the `shouldComponentUpdate()` method and will re-render the view regardless of whether `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false. Because of this using forceUpdate() should be avoided when at all possible.

**2. Passing this.state to the `setState()` method**

The following line of code overcomes the problem with the previous example:

```
this.setState(this.state);
```

Really all this is doing is overwriting the current state with the current state which triggers a re-rendering. This still isn't necessarily the best way to do things, but it does overcome some of the glitches you might encounter using the forceUpdate() method.

Comment: Since setState is batched it's probably safer to do:
`this.setState(prevState => prevState);`

Comment: Not really sure why that is a 'glitch'. The name of the method ('forceUpdate') could not be clearer: force the update always.

Comment: @Zoman, definition of glitch from dictionary: "a small problem or mistake that prevents something from being successful or working as well as it should". `forceUpdate` is not the glitch itself, but can cause glitches and give you unexpected results that need to be overcome via other methods.

Answer (score 5):

We can use this.forceUpdate() as below.

```
       class MyComponent extends React.Component {



      handleButtonClick = ()=>{
          this.forceUpdate();
     }


 render() {

   return (
     <div>
      {Math.random()}
        <button  onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>
        Click me
        </button>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent /> , mountNode);
```

The Element 'Math.random' part in the DOM only gets updated even if you use the setState to re-render the component.

All the answers here are correct supplementing the question for understanding..as we know to re-render a component with out using setState({}) is by  using the forceUpdate().

The above code runs with setState as below.

```
 class MyComponent extends React.Component {



             handleButtonClick = ()=>{
                this.setState({ });
              }


        render() {
         return (
  <div>
    {Math.random()}
    <button  onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
)
  }
 }

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent /> , mountNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another reply to back-up the accepted answer :-)

React discourages the use of `forceUpdate()` because they generally have a very "this is the only way of doing it" approach toward functional programming. This is fine in many cases, but many React developers come with an OO-background, and with that approach, it's perfectly OK to listen to an observable object.

And if you do, you probably know you MUST re-render when the observable "fires", and as so, you SHOULD use `forceUpdate()` and it's actually a plus that `shouldComponentUpdate()` is NOT involved here.

Tools like MobX, that takes an OO-approach, is actually doing this underneath the surface (actually MobX calls `render()` directly)

Answer (score 2):

forceUpdate(), but every time I've ever heard someone talk about it, it's been followed up with you should never use this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it best to avoid forceUpdate(). One way to force re-render is to add dependency of render() on a temporary external variable and change the value of that variable as and when needed.

Here's a code example:

```
class Example extends Component{
   constructor(props){
      this.state = {temp:0};

      this.forceChange = this.forceChange.bind(this);
   }

   forceChange(){
      this.setState(prevState => ({
          temp: prevState.temp++
      })); 
   }

   render(){
      return(
         <div>{this.state.temp &&
             <div>
                  ... add code here ...
             </div>}
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Call this.forceChange() when you need to force re-render.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is calling `setState`, **AND** preserve state:

`this.setState(prevState=>({...prevState}));`

Answer (score 1):

`forceUpdate();` method will work but it is advisable to use `setState();`

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish what you are describing please try this.forceUpdate().

Comment: What does this action do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , if u render components in array , u can use array filter with a unique identifier in each component in order to get a specific component and rerender the component array

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With the use of the `forceUpdate` method, you can force a component to update without changing its state. For example:

```js
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  handleButtonClick = () => {
    this.forceUpdate(); // Force a re-render
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ES6 - I am including an example, which was helpful for me:

In a "short if statement" you can pass empty function like this:

```
isReady ? ()=>{} : onClick
```

This seems to be the shortest approach.

```
()=>{}
```

Comment: Absolut off-topic.

Answer (score -1):

use `useEffect` as a mix of `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, and `componentWillUnmount`, as stated in the React documentation.

To behave like `componentDidMount`, you would need to set your useEffect like this:

```
  useEffect(() => console.log('mounted'), []);
```

The first argument is a callback that will be fired based on the second argument, which is an array of values. If any of the values in that second argument changed, the callback function you defined inside your `useEffect` will be fired.

In the example I'm showing, however, I'm passing an empty array as my second argument, and that will never be changed, so the callback function will be called once when the component mounts.

That kind of summarizes `useEffect`. If instead of an empty value, you have an argument, like:

```
 useEffect(() => {

  }, [props.lang]);
```

That means that every time props.lang changes, your callback function will be called. The `useEffect` will not rerender your component really, unless you're managing some state inside that callback function that could fire a re-render.

If you want to fire a re-render, your render function needs to have a state that you are updating in your `useEffect`.

For example, in here, the render function starts by showing English as the default language and in my use effect I change that language after 3 seconds, so the render is re-rendered and starts showing "spanish".

```
function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("english");

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLang("spanish");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Lang:</h1>
      <p>{lang}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use forceUpdate() for more details check ([forceUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate)).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why leave this answer if for 4 years people have already offered that as a possible solution in this thread?