# Redux, explicitly pass props via Container to wrapped component?

Tags: react-redux

Seems weird, but I wanted to combine a Container's access to the Store with access to properties in the parent container/component where the container would be used.

Container 'DeskContainer' wraps component 'Desk'.  The whole store connection process works.  However, I now want to pass a property explicitly via DeskContainer, and this property does not come from the Redux store.

How to pass that property to the wrapped component?

```
  export default class Widgit extends Component{
    render(){
     return(
       <DeskComponent  foo={this.state.foo} />
     );
    }
  }
```

As to the use case, I was looking at various ways to forceRender the wrapped components and the use of a random key (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35004739/1149606) seemed very easy. I guess not.

Thx

Comment: Sorry, I do no understand, what is wrong with your example?

Comment: Sorry, this was part of a larger long ago problem and now out of date.  I will remove the question.  Thanks.