# How to get to work mobx + react + ui components?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In the project I'm using ui components in the code below is expressed in the form of pseudo clock.
How to make this code work without changing the code clock which in reality is an external library.

And the most important thing that the decision was in the spirit of mobx.

```
class ClockStore {
    @observable data = [
        {id: "hour", value: "00"},
        {id: "min", value: "00"},
        {id: "second", value: "00"},
    ];

    @action
    update(id, value){
        this.data.find(item => item.id === id).value = value;
    }
}

let clockStore = new ClockStore();



@inject('clockStore')
@observer
class App extends Component<any, any> {
    render(){
        return <Clock data={this.props.clockStore.data}></Clock>
    }
}

// it's not my clock this component is taken from github
class Clock extends Component<any, any> {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <ClockFace data={this.props.data} />
                <div className="clock-control"></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ClockFace extends Component<any, any> {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="clock-face">
                {this.props.data.map( ( item, index ) => <ClockSection key={ index }>{ item.value }</ClockSection> )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
class ClockSection extends Component<any, any> {
    render(){
        return (
            <span className="clock-section">{ this.props.children }</span>
        )
    }
}

let stores = { clockStore };

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider {...stores}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector( 'main' )
);

// the code that sets the clock
let count = 0;
document.addEventListener( 'click', () => clockStore.update( 'hour', count ++ ) );
// --------------------------
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @aitchnyu change store > component App is not updated

Comment: Try using the @observer annotation on Clock class

Comment: @aitchnyu I can't do that. Library external.And it still does not help. to earned need to hang on ClockFace.

Comment: If its an external component, you can force your own components to re-render each time there are changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate

Comment: And how I call render if the store does not notifies about the update?)

Answer (score 1):

```
@inject('clockStore')
@observer
class App extends Component<any, any> {
    render(){
        return <Clock data={ mobx.toJS( this.props.clockStore.data } }></Clock>
    }
}
```

or

```
class ClockStore {
    @observable data = [
        {id: "hour", value: "00"},
        {id: "min", value: "00"},
        {id: "second", value: "00"},
    ];

    getData(){
        return toJS( this.data );
    }

    @action
    update(id, value){
        this.data.find(item => item.id === id).value = value;
    }
}
@inject('clockStore')
@observer
class App extends Component<any, any> {
    render(){
        console.log( 'app' );


        return <Clock data={this.props.clockStore.getData()}></Clock>
    }
}
```