# display value inside of looped react native code that has changed with onPress

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

What I am trying to do is repeat a line item and the user will be able to change the quantity of each item on the line. for example

- Soda ............ - 1 +
- Breadsticks .. - 0 +
- etc... .............      - 3 +

so far I have been able to change value and log that the change is happening, but the value that is displayed does not change.

below is what I have so far

```
render() {

    let pizzaSides = this.props.pizzaSidesArray.map((sidesObj) => {

      sidesObj.count = 0;
```

decrement function to reduce the count of the item but not below 0.

```
        decrement = () =>{
          console.log('dec');
          console.log(sidesObj);
          if (sidesObj.count > 0) {
            sidesObj.count--;
          }
        }
```

Increment adds when invoked

```
        increment = () =>{
          console.log('inc');
          console.log(sidesObj);
          sidesObj.count++;
        }

        return (
          <View 
             key={sidesObj.name} 
             style={{
                  paddingTop: 10, 
                  flex: 1, 
                  flexDirection: 'row', 
                  alignItems: 'center',
                  justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>

            <View style={{flex:1.5,flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={ decrement}
                style={{flex:1}}>
                <Text> - </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
```

although the touchable highlights log the change the text below does not change

```
              <Text style={{flex:1}}>
                {sidesObj.count}
              </Text>

              <TouchableHighlight
                onPress={ increment}
                style={{flex:1}}>
                <Text> + </Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

          </View>
        );
    });

    return (
        <View>

          {pizzaSides}
        </View>

    )
}
```

}

Thanks for your help.  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your value in the state. Take a look at the [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html)

Comment: Antone thanks for the tip.  Perhaps I am still missing something.  I have changed the code to update the count value in the array that is stored in redux, and changed the value in the <Text> to access that value from the store, yet it still does not change what is displayed from the initial value.

Comment: What is interesting is now the values will show up when my doc hot reloads.    So perhaps I need to trigger the element to re render somehow.

Comment: Could you send the code you use to set and the code to set the value ? When you change the state in Redux, it should re-render by itself.

Comment: Sure thing.  Here is the file that I currently have in a JS Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pwzgzhh6/

Comment: When I added the forceupdate it worked.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Antone Grandchamp said.

In your component, you can call this.forceUpdate() to force a rerender.

Documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

If I was not using Redux, but was using the default state handling then calling this.setState() would also cause it to re render.

The following question on StackOverflow was helpful.

[Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate)