# On state change of one component re-render second component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Component A
this.state = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2
}

reset () {
    this.setState ({
        x: 3,
        y: 5
    })
}


render () {
    <B x = {this.state.x} y = {this.state.y} onClick = {this.reset.bind(this)}/>
}
```

========================================================

```
Component B

this.state = {
    z: someMethod()
}

someMethod () {
    return this.props.x + this.props.y
}
```

On Click , I am invoking reset Method and updating the state of Component A but how to re render the component B. Now its not updating component B.

```
Tried with 

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {

    this.constructor(nextProps)
}
```

Comment: this.forceUpdate()??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `setState` for the second component too in the `componentWillReceiveProps` function. Constructor is only called on intial render and state should not be only assigned in the contructor if it depends on props

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {

    this.setState({z: nextProps.x + nextProps.y})
}
```

if you want to use someMethod do it like

```
someMethod(props) {
     props? return props.x + props.y : return this.props.x + this.props.y
}
```

and then in componentWillReceiveProps

```
 componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    var z = someMethod(nextProps)
    this.setState({z})
}
```

Comment: someMethod () {
    return this.props.x + this.props.y
}

i am trying to access props form a method. There the x and y value are not updated. Getting the previous value.

Comment: any idea why the props are not getting updated for component B.
The solution is work around or the only solution?

Comment: The thing is componentWillReceive Props is called with the updated props and if you directly call someMethod() from this function, someMethod cannot get access to the new props unless you explicitly pass it the new props which I have done. So the above solution in not a workaround  but a proper solution

Comment: In that case,
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    this.props = nextProps;
    this.setState({z: someMethod})
}

Is this right?

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.constructor(nextProps);
 }

Can I invoke the constructor again from componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: No, you shouldn't, you should call a custom function