# How to force refresh of the text in the div without state or redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a method taking an `array` as parameter, that renders two divs, one displaying the text of the object in the array, second allows user to go to the next text in the array.

However, even though the *variable* is being incremented the `div` doesn't re-render with new text. How I can do this without creating a lot of code like redux?

Code below:

```
const array = [{text: '1st text'}, {text: "2nd text"}]
dialogueReceiver = (array, i) =>{
        let i = 0;
        const increment = () =>{
            i++;
        }
        return(
            <div>

                <div> {array[i].text} </div>
                <div onClick={ () => increment()}> NEXT </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240647/can-i-call-forceupdate-in-stateless-component

Comment: The react way you'll need to update the component via props / setState, just plain javascript you need a to write a simple pub sub method, or write direct to the dom with an eventlistener. But if you are using react you should do things the react way.

Comment: Got it, creating a state for it then, thought I could avoid it for such little thing in this component

Comment: not the best option, but you could have a look at forceUpdate():
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: Perhaps adding `key` attribute to parent `div` do the trick. Change that to `<div key={i}>...rest of the code`