# How to set dynamic Title in NavBar

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Navbar as the root file and I have 3 pages(profile, About, and Home), I want to get data from pages to the root file, e.g. (title = "Profile"), because I want to display the title in the navbar.

my navbar page is listed below

```
import React from "react";

function app(){
return(
<div className="topnav">
          <a
            style={{
              fontWeight: "bold",
              fontSize: "20px",
              position: "absolute",
              margin: "10px",
              color: "#001b2b",
            }}
          >
            {title}
          </a>
<Link exact to="/profile">profile</Link>
<Link exact to="/home">Home</Link>
<Link exact to="/about">About</Link>

</div>
)}
```

if I click profile I want to set the title="profile"

> I stuck to get data from child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its just a title, rather than sending values from child to parent, you can just set a session variable `PageTitle` when you are clicking on any of the menu on navigation bar and refresh the state.
If you are in Profile page the set session variable as below

```
import { ReactSession }  from 'react-client-session';
ReactSession.set("PageTitle", "Profile");
```

and in your root file you can get this session variable as below,

```
this.title = ReactSession.get("PageTitle");  // This will Return "Profile"
```

Comment: its working while clicking the reload.not change automaticaly

Comment: You can use `window.location.reload()` after you set the session variable

Comment: I want to change title without reloading window

Comment: Can you refer this answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/59977132/7633739

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    let a1 = ReactSession.get("PageTitle");
    setTitle(a1);
    
  });

Comment: yeah i put it in useeffect allready but its not working