# Is it possible make function component without useState?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

All my variables in the component are depending on the variable passed in params.

Why should I create state for all of them? I would just create variable with `let`, like:

```js
  let isTiketAdmin: string | null = null;
  let jwt: string | null = null;
  let organizationId: string | undefined = undefined;
  let organization: OrganizationOut | undefined = undefined;
```

and load in value in a method:

```js
const load = () => {
    isTiketAdmin = localStorage.getItem("isTiketAdmin");
    jwt = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    userFbId = localStorage.getItem("userFbId");
    const organizationList = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("organizationList") ?? "[]"
    );
    organizationId = getOrganizationFbIdFromEventId(eventId);
    let organization: OrganizationOut | undefined;
    if (organizationId) {
      organization = organizationList[organizationId];
      let event = organization!.events[props.eventId];
```

And when something needs to be saved/changed, call `load()`.

But then how will rendering work? Do you have any good suggestion to rerender without calling `setState`?

Comment: Do you need to persist the values between renders? If so, why are you avoiding using state?

Comment: Why should I store, if anyway I can fetch them? state variables will cause extra renders only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force re-renders:

1. Class components:
   https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate
2. Hooks: [React - How to force a function component to render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240647/react-how-to-force-a-function-component-to-render/53837442#53837442) (The hooks solution would need a state but that can be extracted out to a separate custom hook)