# re-render a functional component on prop change

Tags: reactjs

Child component accepts a prop and does calculations to show value. On first load, it does work but when parent does passes new value, nothing updates.

Parent:

```
 function Parent(){
       const [v, setV] = useState(0);

    const addNewValue = () =>{
        setV(generateValue({type:'mv', gId: 3})); // generateValue is a function that returns an integer on each call
      }

   return (<div>
          <Child value={v}/>
          <Button onClick={addNewValue}>Calculate</Button>
          
       </div>)

  }
```

Child.js

```
 function Child({value}){
       const [baseValue, setBaseValue] = useState(value);


    useEffect(()=>{
      const calculate = calculate(baseValue);
      setBaseValue(calculate);
     },[baseValue]);

   return (<div>
          <Text>{baseValue}</Text>
       </div>)

  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46240647/react-how-to-force-a-function-component-to-render

Comment: @ArvindMaurya They don't need to force a re-render. A prop change will automatically trigger a re-render, so if they aren't getting that behavior, they're most likely breaking the rules of React. However, I believe *they are* getting a re-render; it's just not doing what they expect.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to `useState` only gets used once on the first render, so you will never see any changes due to `value` updating. However, the `Child` component is still re-rendering

Your `useEffect` should just depend on `value`, since that's what it actually needs to operate on. Otherwise, you'll end up with an infinite loop since every time `baseValue` changes you're updating it again.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  const calculate = calculate(value);
  setBaseValue(calculate);
},[value]);
```

Also note that storing values from props in state is usually an anti-pattern.

The [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-3-identify-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state) provide a very helpful checklist of what should **not** be in state.

> 1. Is it passed in from a parent via props? If so, it probably isn’t state:
> 2. Does it remain unchanged over time? If so, it probably isn’t state.
> 3. Can you compute it based on any other state or props in your component? If so, it isn’t state.

This may fall into #3 (without knowing your full use-case I can't say for sure). In which case you should not use local state in the child at all. If this is true, you should call `calculate` directly each render, or use memoization if the calculation is intensive.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is your effect does not trigger because `baseValue` is not changing in a mounted component. The first time it does. You need to update your effect to this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
      const calculate = calculate(value);
      setBaseValue(calculate);
     },[value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing value props to `useState` will only change `baseValue` in the mounting phase. It won't cause a change in a future update of the value prop

If you want to somehow do the calculation optimally you can memorize the calculated value, otherwise, it seems that removing the state and using props will do the job. take a look [Uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

```
 function Child({value}){

   const baseValue = useMemo(() => calculate(baseValue), [value])
   
   return (<div>
          <Text>{baseValue}</Text>
       </div>)
  }
```