# Display a component on clicking a button in React

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am new to react. How to render a component only after clicking a button in react?

Here in my case on clicking a button I have to display a table which displays the data from the database.

I have attached my code below for your reference, the first component is the button component and below that you can find the components for the table.

Also I would like to know how to refresh a component on clicking a button without refreshing the entire page.

```
var Button = React.createClass({
render: function () {
        return (
           <button type="button">Display</button>

            ); }
});

var EmployeeRow = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.item.EmployeeID}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.FirstName}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.LastName}</td>
                  <td>{this.props.item.Gender}</td>                                                   
              </tr>

            );
    }
});

  var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({

      getInitialState: function(){

          return{
              result:[]
          }
      },
      componentWillMount: function(){

          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
          xhr.onload = function () {
              var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

              this.setState({ result: response });

          }.bind(this);
          xhr.send();
      },
      render: function(){
          var rows = [];
          this.state.result.forEach(function (item) {
              rows.push(<EmployeeRow key={item.EmployeeID} item={item} />);
          });
          return (
<Button />
  <table className="table">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>EmployeeID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Gender</th>               
         </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
          {rows}
      </tbody>
  </table>

  );
  } });

  ReactDOM.render(<EmployeeTable url="api/Employee/GetEmployeeList" />,
          document.getElementById('grid'))
```

Comment: For reloading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate

Comment: Asked a thousand times.  See: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've set up a [sandbox to showcase](https://codesandbox.io/s/z67yyo0wj3) how you can do this.

#### In essence:

1. Initialise state with a boolean set to `false`
2. Render the component conditionally based on this boolean; so initially the component will now show up on the DOM
3. On some action (`onClick`), `setState` on the boolean to `true`
4. The component will re-render since the state changed and will now show the hidden component (since the boolean has been set to `true`)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the code sandbox, very helpful

Comment: Very precise example, thank you for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this.

First Initialize the state with a property **show** with false when the component mounts.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.state = {
    show: false
  };
}
```

Add a function to change the state. (You can use this function to toggle state as well)

```
showTable() {
  this.setState({
    show: true
  });
}
```

Call the function on click of the button.

```
<button onclick="showTable()">
  Show Table
</button>
```

Add your table inside braces along with the expression like this.

```
{
  this.state.show &&
  <table className="table">
     <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>EmployeeID</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>Gender</th>               
         </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody>
          {rows}
      </tbody>
  </table>
}
```

Hope this helps!