# Unable to re-render/refresh a component with setState or forceUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React to build a web application that will display a different quote every time the user clicks a button. I've been hunting for a way to get my component `QuoteGenerator` to re-render/refresh on a button-click, and I've tried all the possibilities presented in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate) with no success.

```
class QuoteGenerator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {num: Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)};
    }

  render() {
    return(
      <div class="quoteBox">
        <div class="quote">
          "{quotes[this.state.num][0]}"<br/>
        </div>
        <button class="button btn" onClick={this.forceUpdate}>New Quote</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Even creating a separate function that runs `this.forceUpdate()` or `this.setState()` and calling that function with `onClick` hasn't worked; I think I must be implementing something wrong. Does anyone see where my error might be?

Comment: Mind to share your `forceUpdate` method?

Comment: @Isaac `forceUpdate` is a react thing

Comment: @Kos: Oppsy did't know that. Just a random ReactNative guy passing by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you only pick the quote once. The constructor will run when the component is instantiated but will *not* run on every click.

Add a method:

```
nextQuote() {
  this.setState({
    num: Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length),
  });
}
```

and call it from your `onClick` (be careful with `this`).

Note: You don't normally need to call [`forceUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) on a react component. Just call `setState`, tell React what changed and the update will happen on its own. From the docs:

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of `forceUpdate()` and only read from `this.props` and `this.state` in `render()`.

Comment: To follow on, React components re-render when their state or props change. So if you want them to re-render in *reaction* to something, that something should logically be some kind of action that changes their state/props. For your example, if you change your `num` state value as Kos has shown, this will re-render your component with the new `num` value and produce the effect you desire

Answer (score 1):

You should use setState if you want to render the component instead of using `this.forceUpdate()`.

You can refer ReactJS official documentation to verify the same because it is not good practice.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

You can write custom method to setState every time you click the button. Also not sure where quotes value is coming from :)

Hopefully this is useful.

```
randomQuote = () => {
  this.setState({
    num: Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.quotes.length)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure `onClick={this.forceUpdate}` would have proper context to do its job. I'd wrap it in an inline function passing context (es6) or bind `this` context to it in the `constructor`

```
<button class="button btn" onClick={() => this.forceUpdate()}>New Quote</button>
```

Furthermore, global `quotes` object seems a bad pattern, you should give that to your component `props`