# Is there a function that returns a promise which gets resolved when any pending changes to a component have been applied in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, lifecycle

I want to show a custom input component and then call its method on a button click:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const customInputRef = useRef(null);

  const [customInputVisible, setCustomInputVisible] = useState(false);

  async function onPress() {
    setCustomInputVisible(true);

    await resolvePendingChanged(); // customInput is not null and can be accessed

    customInputRef.current.customMethod();
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Button onPress={onPress}>Press me!</Button>

      {customInputVisible && <CustomInput ref={customInputRef} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I saw that people use a [custom forceUpdate function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58606536/2419808) in order to trigger a component update but that didn't really help in my case.

In [Svelte](https://svelte.dev/) there's this ["tick" lifecycle hook](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/tick) that does exactly what I need.

> It returns a promise that resolves as soon as any pending state
> changes have been applied to the DOM (or immediately, if there are no
> pending state changes).

Is there an equivalent of Svelte's `tick` in React and if not how can I solve this problem in React?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom hook that uses a [callback ref](http://Callback%20Refs) to set the actual ref, and resolve a promise:

```js
const { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef, useState, useCallback, useMemo } = React;

const CustomInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    customMethod: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }), []);
  
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
});

class Deferred {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject = reject;
    });
  }
}

const waitForComponent = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef(null);
 
  return useMemo(() => {
    let deferred = new Deferred();
    
    return {
      waitLoad(ref) {
        componentRef.current = ref;
        
        if (ref) deferred.resolve();
        else deferred = new Deferred(); // create new Promise when ref is null
      },
      isLoaded: () => deferred.promise,
      componentRef
    };
  }, []);
}

const Parent = () => {
  const { waitLoad, componentRef, isLoaded } = waitForComponent();
  const [customInputVisible, setCustomInputVisible] = useState(false);

  function onPress() {
    setCustomInputVisible(visible => !visible);
     
    // use async here - SO snippet doesn't support async await
    isLoaded().then(() => componentRef.current.customMethod());
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onPress}>Press me!</button>

      {customInputVisible && <CustomInput ref={waitLoad} />}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! However, this will only work if you want to always call `customMethod()` whenever `customInputVisible` is `true`. However, that's not my case. I want to make sure that `customMethod()` is only called `onPress` and not when `customInputVisible` changes.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! It's a super smart solution, although I'm quite surprised that you have to write so much logic for such a simple task. This is solved with a single line in both Svelte and Angular. Still can't understand why React is the most popular front-end library. 

Comment: Because it's an edge case in React, that you rarely encounter. In addition, now you have a reusable hook, that you can use if you encounter similar problems in the future.

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right, although looks pretty common to me. I had to do this in a few different projects, for example, to focus a nested input or in this case I had to add a user tag (@user) when a "Reply" button is clicked. Anyway, thanks a lot again! Saved me lots of time!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit improvement.

```js
const { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef, useState, useCallback, useMemo } = React;

  const CustomInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    customMethod: () => {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }), []);
  
  return <input ref={inputRef} />;
});

class Deferred {
  constructor() {
    this.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolve = resolve;
      this.reject = reject;
    });
  }
}

const useWaitForComponent = () => {
   
  return useMemo(() => {
      let deferred = new Deferred();
      const waitLoad = (ref)=> {
        
        if (ref) deferred.resolve(ref);
        else deferred = new Deferred(); // create new Promise when ref is null
      }
      const isLoaded = () => deferred.promise
    return [waitLoad, isLoaded];
  }, []);
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [ refCustomInputWait, isCustomInputLoaded ] = useWaitForComponent();
  const [customInputVisible, setCustomInputVisible] = useState(false);

  function onPress() {
    setCustomInputVisible(visible => !visible);
     
    // use async here - SO snippet doesn't support async await
    isCustomInputLoaded ().then((ref) => ref.customMethod());
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onPress}>Press me!</button>

      {customInputVisible && <CustomInput ref={refCustomInputWait} />}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```