# Class works fine normally but stops working when instantiated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, oop, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm making a bluetooth remote in React Native. I have a class BLE that works on it's own, but parts of it don't work when I it in another class.

```
import BLE from './Core/BLE.js'

const myBLE = new BLE();

function DebugScreen(){
    useEffect(() => {
      myBLE.componentDidMount();
    }, []);
    
    return(
      <ScrollView>
        <Text>State: {myBLE.state.info}</Text>
        <Text>Devices: {JSON.stringify(myBLE.state.ble_devices)}</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
  
export default DebugScreen;
```

The devices text box shows data just fine, but state does not. I verified that this was not simply the state not refreshing by putting a timer on the screen.

My question is, is there a fundamental difference between code running in an instantiated class and one that isn't?

Comment: Are you trying to run react component as a normal class instead of using it as intended?

Comment: The view won‘t update when myBLE properties were changing.
For testing try to use a force update with setInterval to refresh the view manually
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53215285/how-can-i-force-a-component-to-re-render-with-hooks-in-react

Comment: @MichaelBahl I put a timer in like this:

const [time, setTime] = useState(Date.now());

    useEffect(() => {
      myBLE.componentDidMount();
      const interval = setInterval(() => setTime(Date.now()), 1000);
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }, []);
It still only shows the ble_devices, but at least they are refreshing now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Instantiating classes the normal JS way is bad practice in React/React Native. To have top level code and information, I need to use context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).