# Run render and reconciler on children only

Tags: reactjs

I want to skip rendering of container, but run rendering and reconciliation for the `childeren` passed via `props`. In the next example you can click it and see

```
render
render2
render value 2001
render value 3001
```

but I want it to be

```
render
render value 1001
render2
render value 2001
render value 3001
```

So I want `Value` `1001` to render, but without rendering `Wrapper1`.

How can I do that?

```js
class Value extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log("render value " + this.props.value);
    return this.props.value;
  }
}

class Wrapper1 extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render1");
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class Wrapper2 extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("render2");
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 };

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 }))}>
        <Wrapper1><Value value={1000 + this.state.count} /></Wrapper1>
        {" "}
        <Wrapper2><Value value={2000 + this.state.count} /></Wrapper2>
        {" "}
        <Value value={3000 + this.state.count} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Why do you need `Wrapper1`? And why do you want to skip rendering it? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate

Answer (score 1):

To rerender children without rerendering `Wrapper1` you need to change their state somehow. Note that `props` of `Value` inside `Wrapper1` never change. So forced renders will output the same value unless you pass it some other way. There is some bad code for example:

```js
class Value extends React.Component {
  state = {value: null};

  componentDidMount() {
    if (typeof(this.props.setUpdater) === 'function') this.props.setUpdater(
      value => this.setState({value})
    );
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render value ", this.state.value, this.props.value);
    return this.state.value || this.props.value;
  }
}

class Wrapper1 extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  render() {
    console.log("render1");
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class Wrapper2 extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("render2");
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { count: 0 };

  render() {
    console.log("render");
    if (typeof(this.state.updater) === 'function') this.state.updater(1000 + this.state.count);
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.setState(({ count }) => ({ count: count + 1 }))}>
        <Wrapper1><Value value={1000 + this.state.count} setUpdater={updater => this.setState({updater})}/></Wrapper1>
        {" "}
        <Wrapper2><Value value={2000 + this.state.count} /></Wrapper2>
        {" "}
        <Value value={3000 + this.state.count} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)