# Loading Screen on Next.js page transition

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to implement a loading screen when changing routes in my Next.js app, for example /home -> /about.

My current implementation is as follows. I am setting the initial loaded state to false and then changing it on *componentDidMount*. I am also calling the *Router.events.on* function inside *componentDidMount* to change the loading state when the route change starts.

***_app.js* in pages folder**

```
class MyApp extends App {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loaded: true });
    Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => this.setState({ loaded: false }));
    Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => this.setState({ loaded: true }));
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    const { loaded } = this.state;

    const visibleStyle = {
      display: '',
      transition: 'display 3s',
    };
    const inVisibleStyle = {
      display: 'none',
      transition: 'display 3s',
    };
    return (
      <Container>
        <>
          <span style={loaded ? inVisibleStyle : visibleStyle}>
            <Loader />
          </span>
          <span style={loaded ? visibleStyle : inVisibleStyle}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </span>
        </>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

This works perfectly fine but I feel like there may be a better solution more elegant solution. Is this the only way which isn't cumbersome to implement this loading feature or is there an alternative ?

Comment: You might want to move `inVisibleStyle` and `visibleStyle` outside of the `render()` method

Answer (score 71):

Using the new hook api,
this is how I would do it..

```js
function Loading() {
    const router = useRouter();

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleStart = (url) => (url !== router.asPath) && setLoading(true);
        const handleComplete = (url) => (url === router.asPath) && setLoading(false);

        router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleStart)
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleComplete)
        router.events.on('routeChangeError', handleComplete)

        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleStart)
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleComplete)
            router.events.off('routeChangeError', handleComplete)
        }
    })
    
    return loading && (<div>Loading....{/*I have an animation here*/}</div>);
}
```

Now `<Loading/>` is going to show up whenever the route will change...
I animate this using react-spring, but you can use any library you prefer to do this.

You can even take a step further and modify when the component shows up by modifying the `handleStart` and `handleComplete` methods that gets a `url`.

Comment: Hi, I would like to see how this is implemented in a full _app.js component. I will really appreciate if you can be so kind as to post a link to the file.

Comment: It seems using `router.asPath` instead of `router.pathname` is more accurate if using dynamic routes.

Comment: `router.asPath` in handleComplete doesn't seem to get resolved to the destination path in time. So I decided to not compare the url before `setLoading` and it works.

Comment: Hmm.. Removing the URL check isn't recommended because this can update the state even if there is no change in the URL. If you check the NextJS documentation, it mentions the router.asPath does not include the basePath and the locale. So please confirm whether you are using any those in your application so that I can update the code

Comment: in my case, I'm not compare on `routeChangeComplete` , I just set the state to false. because on `routeChangeComplete` the `router.asPath` value not change on first invoke, so I have to invoke it twice to change `router.asPath` value.

Comment: That works too (you may want to handle `routeChangeError`). However this requires you to call this function in every page. How I used the example above is by adding it to the `_app.js`. In this case I would have to listen for the `routeChangeStart` too.

Comment: @bubbleChaser it works fine for me. and also query pram changing is not detected. that's cool

Comment: I confirm behavior by @dhidy. on `routeChangeComplete`  `router.asPath` has still the old pathvalue . Example starting from /a and clicking /b link, on routeChangeComplete router.asPath has url /a (NOT /b)

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work for me. The `loading` is always true after the first loading.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks. Just need find a way to export the function to use for all my pages.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with query params.
Skipping the equality check made it work.
Is there any reason the equality check is added ? @RohitKrishnan

Comment: @KaranShah yeah you need to compare the current path and the path that it is routing to.. if it is the same you don't need a loading state.. otherwise even clicking on the current page's link will trigger the loading state. You can skip the equality check if you don't mind this.

Comment: This is not working on App Router anymore. What is the workaround?

Answer (score 67):

(Edit: If you're using the App Router, please see Jeremy Bernier's comment [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624695/loading-screen-on-next-js-page-transition/70086644?noredirect=1#comment135424552_70086644), below)

For anyone coming across this in 2023 (and using the old page router), the package [nextjs-progressbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-progressbar) makes this super easy. In your Next.js `_app.js` (or `.jsx`, `.tsx`, etc.), simply add the ` anywhere in the default export, like below:

```
import NextNProgress from 'nextjs-progressbar';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <NextNProgress />
      <Component {...pageProps} />;
    </>
  );
}
```

And done!

[Demo](https://demo-nextjs-progressbar.vercel.app/) and screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Great answer. Works for me.

Comment: Just great, works perfectly out of the box with minimal code.

Comment: I was just looking for something like this tnx!

Comment: you can even make it look better and change the css entirely: `<NextNProgress color='linear-gradient(90deg, #b656cb, #10a1a0)'/>`

Comment: Doesn't work with new App Router, but this package works: "nextjs-toploader" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-toploader)

Comment: Thanks for the note, Jeremy! I edited the post to point to your suggestion.

Answer (score 53):

Why not use `nprogress` as follows in `_app.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';

NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: publicRuntimeConfig.NProgressShowSpinner });

Router.onRouteChangeStart = () => {
  // console.log('onRouteChangeStart triggered');
  NProgress.start();
};

Router.onRouteChangeComplete = () => {
  // console.log('onRouteChangeComplete triggered');
  NProgress.done();
};

Router.onRouteChangeError = () => {
  // console.log('onRouteChangeError triggered');
  NProgress.done();
};

export default class MyApp extends App { ... }
```

Link to [nprogress](http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress).

You also need to include style file as well. If you put the css file in `static` directory, then you can access the style as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/nprogress.css" />
```

Make sure the CSS is available in all pages...

It will work for all your routes changing.

Comment: nprogress doesn't allow custom loaders right ? It only has that loading stripe on the top.

Comment: That's right. However you can change the nprogress to anything else you want.

Comment: How do you change it ? I cant find it in the nprogress documentation.

Comment: what I meant was to use your custom component

Comment: For someone reading this in the future, you can change the CSS by copying the styles from nprogress.css (inside node_modules) and pasting it in your own CSS/SCSS file and import your CSS file instead of nprogress.css file in your _app.js. You can fiddle with the CSS as animations are pretty basic.

Comment: For people using Next.js, there's this now: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-progressbar

Answer (score 21):

**New Update with NProgress:**

```
import Router from 'next/router'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from 'next/head'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'

Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => {
  console.log(`Loading: ${url}`)
  NProgress.start()
})
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => NProgress.done())
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done())

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        {/* Import CSS for nprogress */}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/nprogress.css" />
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```

If you use Tailwind CSS, copy the code from here: https://unpkg.com/nprogress@0.2.0/nprogress.css and paste the code into your global CSS file.

if you want to disable the spinner add the below code in your `_app.tsx/jsx` file and remove the spinner styles from CSS.

```
NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: false });
```

Source Links:

- https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress
- https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Comment: Just in case, you have to save `nprogress.css` in `/public`

Answer (score 4):

Progress bar like NProgress in 90 lines of code (vs NProgress v0.2.0 is 470 lines .js + 70 lines .css):

```
import { useEffect, useReducer, useRef } from 'react';

import { assert } from './assert';
import { wait } from './wait';
import { getRandomInt } from './getRandomNumber';

let waitController: AbortController | undefined;

// https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/db8a8106cc93ae797ea968d78ea28047
export function useProgressBar({
  trickleMaxWidth = 94,
  trickleIncrementMin = 1,
  trickleIncrementMax = 5,
  dropMinSpeed = 50,
  dropMaxSpeed = 150,
  transitionSpeed = 600
} = {}) {
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/66436476
  const [, forceUpdate] = useReducer(x => x + 1, 0);

  // https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14010#issuecomment-433788147
  const widthRef = useRef(0);

  function setWidth(value: number) {
    widthRef.current = value;
    forceUpdate();
  }

  async function trickle() {
    if (widthRef.current < trickleMaxWidth) {
      const inc =
        widthRef.current +
        getRandomInt(trickleIncrementMin, trickleIncrementMax); // ~3
      setWidth(inc);
      try {
        await wait(getRandomInt(dropMinSpeed, dropMaxSpeed) /* ~100 ms */, {
          signal: waitController!.signal
        });
        await trickle();
      } catch {
        // Current loop aborted: a new route has been started
      }
    }
  }

  async function start() {
    // Abort current loops if any: a new route has been started
    waitController?.abort();
    waitController = new AbortController();

    // Force the show the JSX
    setWidth(1);
    await wait(0);

    await trickle();
  }

  async function complete() {
    assert(
      waitController !== undefined,
      'Make sure start() is called before calling complete()'
    );
    setWidth(100);
    try {
      await wait(transitionSpeed, { signal: waitController.signal });
      setWidth(0);
    } catch {
      // Current loop aborted: a new route has been started
    }
  }

  function reset() {
    // Abort current loops if any
    waitController?.abort();
    setWidth(0);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // Abort current loops if any
      waitController?.abort();
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return {
    start,
    complete,
    reset,
    width: widthRef.current
  };
}
```

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useProgressBar } from './useProgressBar';

const transitionSpeed = 600;

// https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/db8a8106cc93ae797ea968d78ea28047
export function RouterProgressBar(
  props?: Parameters<typeof useProgressBar>[0]
) {
  const { events } = useRouter();

  const { width, start, complete, reset } = useProgressBar({
    transitionSpeed,
    ...props
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    events.on('routeChangeStart', start);
    events.on('routeChangeComplete', complete);
    events.on('routeChangeError', reset); // Typical case: "Route Cancelled"

    return () => {
      events.off('routeChangeStart', start);
      events.off('routeChangeComplete', complete);
      events.off('routeChangeError', reset);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return width > 0 ? (
    // Use Bootstrap, Material UI, Tailwind CSS... to style the progress bar
    <div
      className="progress fixed-top bg-transparent rounded-0"
      style={{
        height: 3, // GitHub turbo-progress-bar height is 3px
        zIndex: 1091 // $zindex-toast + 1 => always visible
      }}
    >
      <div
        className="progress-bar"
        style={{
          width: `${width}%`,
          //transition: 'none',
          transition: `width ${width > 1 ? transitionSpeed : 0}ms ease`
        }}
      />
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

How to use:

```
// pages/_app.tsx

import { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';

import { RouterProgressBar } from './RouterProgressBar';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My title</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My description" />
      </Head>

      <RouterProgressBar />

      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
```

More here: https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/db8a8106cc93ae797ea968d78ea28047

Answer (score 3):

[Since v 13.0](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13#data-fetching)

Note that in many cases u can just simply create file `loading.tsx`

*With this convention, you can show an instant loading state from the server while the content of a route segment loads. The new content is automatically swapped in once rendering is complete.*

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming

Comment: Yes, this is the way in last versions of Next js.

Answer (score 1):

It is considerably easy by using `nprogress`

```
"use client"

import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import NProgress from 'nprogress'
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css'

export default async function Home() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()

  useEffect(() => {
    NProgress.done();
    return () => {
      NProgress.start();
    };
  }, [pathname, searchParams]);

  return (
    <>
     ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: This works in /app dir, thanks.