# How to create a progress bar in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, loading

I'm trying to create a Progress Bar which is at the very top of the website and each time you load the page, you see that Bar filling up.

I want to implement the same functionality in Next.js, but I'm struggling to do so. There are many libraries for the loading bar, but they all ask for a `value` prop which basically indicates how much the bar is filled, but I cannot find a way to get this `value` prop dynamically. I don't want to hardcode it, I want it to fill up as the page gets loaded.

Is there any way that I can find the value of the `value` prop dynamically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading Screen on next js page transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624695/loading-screen-on-next-js-page-transition)

Comment: Smaller alternative to NProgress: https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/db8a8106cc93ae797ea968d78ea28047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple ways of doing that, nextjs have the Router import, so you can use the events [see here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents)

With that in mind you could create the visual component and if you really want to show on every page change, you could use this with your `_app.tsx/jsx` with the `useEffect` hook. Just don't forget to cleanup the events after listening to them

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60756105/13436765) does a great job showing it how to implement it, it's a great reference and very generic, so you can custom as much as you want

Answer (score 0):

In `__app.js` or `__app.tsx`

```
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
```

add the CSS for NProgress in the head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/nprogress.css" />`

```
Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => NProgress.start());
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done());
```