# Loading Screen when reloading page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I see some posts using events like `routeChangeStart`, `routeChangeComplete`, etc... to make loading screens. It works well when changing the route, but when reloading page(<kbd>F5</kbd>), these events don't fire.
How would you make a loading screen when reloading the page? Thanks

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624695/loading-screen-on-next-js-page-transition

Comment: @MichaelFlores That question is about client-side page transitions, not initial page load like OP is asking about.

Comment: @juliomalves you're right