# React: re render componet after button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

How do I make page refresh or reender content in page after I click submit button? I've trying to put `window.location.reload()` (I know that not the React way, `this.forceUpdate()` have same result) in submit functions(`closeTicket()`, `openTicketSubmit()`) but POST request don't get response

OpenTickets.js

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import CardConversation from './CardConversation.jsx';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            people: [],
            send_to_number: "",
            message_body: ""
        };

        this.closeTicket = this.closeTicket.bind(this);
        this.openTicketsReply = this.openTicketsReply.bind(this);
        this.openTicketsSubmit = this.openTicketsSubmit.bind(this);
        this.getPhoneNumberOpenTickets = this.getPhoneNumberOpenTickets.bind(this);
    }

    openTicketsReply = async e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };

    getPhoneNumberOpenTickets = async e => {
        this.setState({
            send_to_number: e
        });
    };

    openTicketsSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("send_to_number", this.state.send_to_number.slice(1));
        formData.set("message_body", this.state.message_body);
        axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "/outgoingsms",
            data: formData,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
        })
    };

    closeTicket = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("customernum", this.state.send_to_number.slice(1));
        axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "/closeticket",
            data: formData,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
        })
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPeopleData();
    }

    getPeopleData = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/getongoing?limit=10`);
            this.setState({ people: data });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error: ", e);
        }
    };

    render() {
        const {
            closeTicket,
            openTicketsSubmit,
            getPhoneNumberOpenTickets,
            openTicketsReply
        } = this;

        return this.state.people.map(person => (
            <CardConversation
                person={person}
                closeTicket={closeTicket}
                openTicketsSubmit={openTicketsSubmit}
                getPhoneNumberOpenTickets={getPhoneNumberOpenTickets}
                openTicketsReply={openTicketsReply}
            />
        ));
    }
}
```

CardConversation.jsx

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Accordion, Card, Form, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

const CardConversation = ({
                              person,
                              closeTicket,
                              openTicketsSubmit,
                              getPhoneNumberOpenTickets,
                              openTicketsReply,
                          }) => {
    const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);

    // Handlers
    const handleSubmit = useCallback(
        e => {
            openTicketsSubmit(e);
        },
        [openTicketsSubmit]
    );

    const handleCloseTicket = useCallback(
        e => {
            closeTicket(e);
        },
        [closeTicket],
    );

    const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
        getPhoneNumberOpenTickets(person);
    },
        [person, getPhoneNumberOpenTickets]);

    const handleChange = useCallback(
        e => {
            openTicketsReply(e);
        },
        [openTicketsReply]
    );

    // Methods
    const fetchConversation = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(
                "/getconvfornum?customer_number=" + person.slice(1)
            );
            setConversation(data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error: ", e);
        }
    }, [person, conversation]);

    // Effects
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchConversation(person)
    }, [person]);

    return (
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="button" eventKey="0">
                        Conversation {person.indexOf(person)+1+ '    '}
                        Phone number: {person}
                    </Accordion.Toggle>
                </Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                    <Card.Body>
                        {conversation.map(message => (
                            <div>
                                <p>{message.from}</p>
                                <p>{message.body}</p>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <br />
                            <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formPlaintextPassword">
                                <Col sm="10">
                                    <Form.Control
                                        type="text"
                                        placeholder="Reply"
                                        name="message_body"
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                    />
                                </Col>
                                <Button type={"submit"}
                                        onClick={handleClick} column sm="2">
                                    Reply
                                </Button>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>
                        <Form onSubmit={handleCloseTicket}>
                            <Form.Group>
                                <Col sm="11">
                                    <Button type={"submit"}
                                            onClick={handleClick} column sm="4">
                                        Close Ticket
                                    </Button>
                                </Col>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Form>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
            <br />
        </Accordion>
    );
};

export default CardConversation;
```

Comment: Presumably when you close a ticket it's going to result in some form of state being changed? e.g. `ticket.closed = true`?

Comment: I tried this but it's not help

Comment: @MiXProjectT show what you have done?

Comment: i add `closed: false` in `this.state` and do `then(() => { this.setState({ closed: true}); }` after axios and delete `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @MiXProjectT too early, add a callback to your Axios call and then run `setState` in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to re-render would be to change the state variable on the submission of the Axios request causing the component to re-render automatically.
Example:

```
axios({...}).then(resp => {
 this.setState({message_body:'',send_to_number:''}); // will cause to re-render
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make the component re-render by updating its `state` ( after the POST ) :

```
closeTicket = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.set("customernum", this.state.send_to_number.slice(1));
  axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/closeticket",
      data: formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.setState({ /* */ })
    // or
    // this.forceUpdate();
  })
};
```

Comment: i add  `closed: false` in `this.state` and do `then(() => {
            this.setState({ closed: true});
        })` page not re render

Comment: updating the state will refresh the component, remove `e.preventDefault();` from `openTicketsSubmit` if you want the page to refresh, but i wouldn't reommend that, try updating the state in `openTicketsSubmit` like in `closeTicket`

Comment: i delete 'e.preventDefault();' but it's not even sending post request anymore

Answer (score 2):

React will rerender components once the state changes, which means that what you need is to change the state once the submit button is clicked. Since the submit button is inside the PersonList component and you also want to reload PersonList, you want to change the state of PersonList when the submit button is clicked.

Here is what you might want to do:
1) add a 'reload' state to PersonList, defaulting it to false. This will tell the component if you need to reload or not.
2) pass a function that sets the state of PersonList's reload value into the child component, in this case CardConversion. something like this.setState({reload:!this.state.reload}) should do.
3) when you finish handling what you need to handle within CardConversion, call your passed function to set the parent's state value, and the whole component should reload.

```
this.state = {
  reload: false
  ...
}

...

shouldReload() {
  this.setState({reload:!this.state.reload});
}

...

<CardConversation
  person={person}
  closeTicket={closeTicket}
  openTicketsSubmit={openTicketsSubmit}
  getPhoneNumberOpenTickets={getPhoneNumberOpenTickets}
  openTicketsReply={openTicketsReply}
  reloadParent={this.shouldReload.bind(this)}
/>
```

and on CardConversation

```
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
  getPhoneNumberOpenTickets(person);
  this.props.reloadParent();
},
```

Comment: in `const handleClick` says that `this.props.reloadParent();` is unresolved function or method. i tried to fix it but still no result. this is how code looks right now [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-violet-4mwrz)

Comment: @mixproject your link doesn't have a working example but I tried to scan the code quickly and see if I can see an issue. Could it be that you are not binding "this" into the shouldReload function? Also, please check what props you are passing by just outputting them into the console: console.log(this.props). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

in `opentickets.js`

create a function updatePeople and in that function call `this.getPeopleData();`
eg

```
updatePeople = () =>{
    this.getPeopleData();
  }
```

then in

```
 return this.state.people.map(person => (
            <CardConversation
                person={person}
                closeTicket={closeTicket}
                openTicketsSubmit={openTicketsSubmit}
                getPhoneNumberOpenTickets={getPhoneNumberOpenTickets}
                openTicketsReply={openTicketsReply}
                refreshPeople = {this.updatePeople}

            />
        ));
```

in `cardConversion.jsx`

when you click the close button or whichever button gets you back to openTickets, put the callback function

`this.props.refreshPeople();`

because you have componentDidMount, everytime you call whatever is in componentDidMount, it will update the information and re render it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regarding you are not getting any data issue, you can check [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), and how they use post:

```js
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    // where you can setState here
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Mainly axios are handling the data asynchronously. By that, once you call the api, React will executes next line of code.

For more discussion of how to force update the component, you can check this post: [Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate), which explain how to update component very well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, what you're trying to do is reload the people list. If that's the case, you can solve it in two ways:

1. In both `axios` API calls, add `.then()` block and call `this.getPeopleData()`.
2. Instead of re-fetching people's data, you get the added/deleted post data and update state in the `.then()` block with `setState()`.

I suggest you to adopt Option 2, because fetching the list again will require more time for you to get the refreshed list.

Either way, just adding `this.forceUpdate()` to your `.then()` block will not give you the updated list. It won't do anything actually to the UI. (though it makes it re-render)

Answer (score 0):

CardConversatio.jsx

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Accordion, Card, Form, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

const CardConversation = ({
  person,
  closeTicket,
  openTicketsSubmit,
  getPhoneNumberOpenTickets,
  openTicketsReply,
  getPhoneToCloseTicket,
}) => {
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);
  const [trigger, fireUpdate] = useState(false);

  // Handlers

  const renderConversation = useCallback(() => {
    return conversation.map(message => (
      <div key={message.date.$date + person}>
        <p>{message.from}</p>
        <p>{message.body}</p>
      </div>
    ));
  }, [conversation, person]);

  const fetchConversation = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        "/getconvfornum?customer_number=" + person.slice(1)
      );
      setConversation(data);
      console.log("fetch ", data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error: ", e);
    }
  }, [person]);

  const handleClick = useCallback(async () => {
    await getPhoneNumberOpenTickets(person);
    setTimeout(() => fetchConversation(person), 500);
  }, [getPhoneNumberOpenTickets, person, fetchConversation]);

  const handleClickClose = useCallback(async () => {
    await getPhoneToCloseTicket(person);
  }, [person, getPhoneToCloseTicket]);


  const handleChange = useCallback(
    e => {
      openTicketsReply(e);
    },
    [openTicketsReply]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect");
    fetchConversation(person);
  }, [fetchConversation, person]);

  return (
    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
      <Card>
        <Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="button" eventKey="0">
            Conversation {person.indexOf(person) + 1 + "    "}
            Phone number: {person}
          </Accordion.Toggle>
        </Card.Header>
        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
          <Card.Body>
            {renderConversation()}
            <Form>
              <br />
              <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formPlaintextPassword">
                <Col sm="10">
                  <Form.Control
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Reply"
                    name="message_body"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </Col>
                <Button onClick={handleClick} column sm="2">
                  Reply
                </Button>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group>
                <Col sm="11">
                  <Button onClick={handleClickClose} column sm="4">
                    Close Ticket
                  </Button>
                </Col>
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
          </Card.Body>
        </Accordion.Collapse>
      </Card>
      <br />
    </Accordion>
  );
};

export default CardConversation;
```

OpenTickets.js

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import CardConversation from './CardConversation.jsx';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            people: [],
            send_to_number: "",
            message_body: "",
            closed: false
        };

        this.closeTicket = this.closeTicket.bind(this);
        this.openTicketsReply = this.openTicketsReply.bind(this);
        this.openTicketsSubmit = this.openTicketsSubmit.bind(this);
        this.getPhoneNumberOpenTickets = this.getPhoneNumberOpenTickets.bind(this);
        this.getPhoneToCloseTicket = this.getPhoneToCloseTicket.bind(this);
    }

    openTicketsReply = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            message_body: e.target.value
        });
    };

    getPhoneNumberOpenTickets = async e => {
        //e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            send_to_number: e
        }, async () => await this.openTicketsSubmit());
    };

    getPhoneToCloseTicket = async e => {
        this.setState({
            send_to_number: e
        }, async () => this.closeTicket());
    };

    openTicketsSubmit = async e => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("send_to_number", this.state.send_to_number.slice(1));
        formData.set("message_body", this.state.message_body);
        axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "/outgoingsms",
            data: formData,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
        }).then(resp => {
            this.setState({ closed: true });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    };

    closeTicket = async e => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("customernum", this.state.send_to_number.slice(1));
        axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "/closeticket",
            data: formData,
            headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
        }).then(resp => {
            this.setState({ closed: true });
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
    };


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPeopleData();
    }

    getPeopleData = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/getongoing?limit=10`);
            this.setState({ people: data });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("error: ", e);
        }
    };

    render() {
        const {
            closeTicket,
            getPhoneNumberOpenTickets,
            openTicketsReply,
            getPhoneToCloseTicket
        } = this;

        return this.state.people.map(person => (
            <CardConversation
                key={person}
                person={person}
                closeTicket={closeTicket}
                getPhoneNumberOpenTickets={getPhoneNumberOpenTickets}
                openTicketsReply={openTicketsReply}
                getPhoneToCloseTicket={getPhoneToCloseTicket}
            />
        ));
    }
}
```