# How to add Spinner at specific route?

Tags: next.js

I get this code in question:[nextjs getServerSideProps show loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60755316/nextjs-getserversideprops-show-loading)

```
import Router from "next/router";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const start = () => {
      console.log("start");
      setLoading(true);
    };
    const end = () => {
      console.log("findished");
      setLoading(false);
    };
    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", start);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", end);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeError", end);
    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", start);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", end);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeError", end);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

It work for me, but with all route, I just want to work with some route, and route have dynamic query, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to define a list of routes that you don't want to have a loading state. For example

```
//`/details/` can be a dynamic route like `/details/1`, `/details/2`, etc.
const EXCEPTED_ROUTES = ['/details/'] //routes based on definitions
```

And then you can do it with URL param in [`routeChangeStart`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage-6) event

```
const start = (url) => {
   const isURLMatched = EXCEPTED_ROUTES.some(exceptedRoute => url.startsWith(exceptedRoute))
   if(isURLMatched) { //the condition here is your choice
      return //should not set loading state
   }
   console.log("start");
   setLoading(true);
};
```