# How to trigger a CSS animation on EVERY TIME a react component re-renders

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to play an animation on a react component every time it rerenders due to prop change:

react:

```
function Card({ cardText }) {
  return <div className="roll-out">{cardText}<div/>
}
```

So I did css:

```css
@keyframes rollout {
  0% { transform: translateY(-100px); }
  100% { transform: none; }
}

.roll-out {
  animation: rollout 0.4s;
}
```

However, the animation only plays once, on the initial render. I want to play it every time `<Card />` re-renders due to `cardText` change. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Add a key like this:

```
function Card({ cardText }) {
  return <div key={cardText} className="roll-out">{cardText}<div/>
}
```

In your code, when the div re-renders, react only changes its inner text. Adding a key will make react think it's a different div when the key changes, so it'll unmount it and mount again.

Comment: Oh wow. So react re-renders the html elements whose key has changed.

Comment: Thanks. This is an easy and just working solution without hacking via setState and timeouts.

Comment: nice real time example of how react understands the key has been changed and update the new node. nice man

Comment: Absolute life-saver.

Answer (score 13):

The trick here is to use a random `key` field on your card element. React's diffing algorithm considers elements with the same key as the same, so randomizing the key will make react consider each rerendered element as new, so will removed the old element from the DOM and add a brand new one

Here is a demo using @aXuser264 's code as a base.

```js
class Card extends React.Component{
   onClick = ()=>this.forceUpdate();
   render(){
       return <div key={Math.random()} className="roll-out" onClick={this.onClick}> {
    this.props.cardText
     } </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( (<Card cardText="Hey There" />) , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
@keyframes rollout {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.roll-out {
  animation: .4s rollout;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

To force element to *re-render* you can simply change its `key` prop which will trigger a render making react think its another element

Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35004739

```js
function Card({
  cardText
}) {
  return <div className = "roll-out" > {
    cardText
  } </div>
}

ReactDOM.render( (<Card cardText="Hey There" />) , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
@keyframes rollout {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.roll-out {
  animation: .4s rollout;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```