# How to add CSS animation to specific re-rendered item in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to play CSS animation on every time stock property of items state re-renders(increase button clicks)

React code:

```js
const RenderingApp = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { fruit: 'banana', stock: 10, id: 0 },
    { fruit: 'apple', stock: 5, id: 1 },
  ]);

  const renderList = () => {
    return items.map((item, index) => {
      const handleIncrease = () => {
        const newItems = items.map(i => {
          if (i.id === item.id) {
            return { ...i, stock: i.stock + 1 };
          } else {
            return i;
          }
        });
        setItems(newItems);
      };

      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <div>{item.fruit}</div>
          <div className="add-color">{item.stock}</div>
          <button onClick={handleIncrease}>increase</button>
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return <div>{renderList()}</div>;
};
```

CSS code:

```css
.add-color {
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(5, 149, 5);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

However, animation plays once at initial render. To solve this problem, I added key value on the stock's div as it was answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186710/how-to-trigger-a-css-animation-on-every-time-a-react-component-re-renders), like so:

```
 <div key={Math.random()} className="add-color">{item.stock}</div>
```

but now as I click increase button, for example of second item's button, both stock's div re-renders, therefore animation plays for both of them simultaneously:

[image] next click: [image]

before I added key value re-render only happened just clicked item's stock div but not played animation, though after adding key value, re-render happens for both item's stock div.

How can I achieve to play animation for just clicked item's stock div? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a CSS animation on EVERY TIME a react component re-renders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186710/how-to-trigger-a-css-animation-on-every-time-a-react-component-re-renders)

Comment: It doesn't. As I mentioned, I have already added key but it triggers all items, I need to play CSS animation for specific item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you essentially want to do is [restart a CSS animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268508/restart-animation-in-css3-any-better-way-than-removing-the-element) for a particular element. To be honest, I'm not sure of a better way to do this in React than by accessing the DOM element with a reference.

You can do this by making each item its own component and using `useRef` to get access to the DOM element you want to animate, and then apply the animation code in the linked stack overflow answer above.

```
const RenderItem = ({ item, handleIncrease }) => {
    const stockElem = useRef()

    const animate = () => {
        let s = stockElem.current
        s.style.animation = 'none'
        // I had to do "let x =" here because my create-react-app config was yelling at me
        let x = s.offsetHeight; // trigger reflow
        s.style.animation = null
    }

    const increase = () => {
        handleIncrease()
        animate()
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{item.fruit}</div>
            <div ref={stockElem} className="add-color">{item.stock}</div>
            <button onClick={increase}>increase</button>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then in your main component, render each item:

```
return <RenderItem key={item.id} item={item} handleIncrease={handleIncrease} />;
```

### The `key` approach

There is a way to do this with `key`, **but I don't like it** since it goes against `key`'s purpose as defined by React, and can probably lead to problems down the road.

```
return (
  <div key={`${item.id}-${item.stock}`}>
    <div>{item.fruit}</div>
    <div className="add-color">{item.stock}</div>
    <button onClick={handleIncrease}>increase</button>
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
);
```

The key line is `` <div key={`${item.id}-${item.stock}`}> ``. React will un-mount and remount an element whose key changes. So, this utilizes the uniqueness of `item.id` combined with the fact that `item.stock` changes to rerender the div.

Again, even though the first solution I provided is more verbose, it's definitely more canonical.