# Array element not updating to the opposite of its previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the state of particular index of my array when a function is called. However, the value is not updated despite clicking multiple times.

I have the following array extracted from the const `EDITABLES` in `componentDidMount`:

```
values = EDITABLES.map((data) => {
  return {
    id: data.id,
    value: financials[data.id],
    table: data.table,
    add: false,
    minus: false,
  };
});

this.setState({
        values,
      });
```

When rendering I map the array like so:

```
{EDITABLES.map((data, index) => {
              
              console.log(values[index]?.add, "bool"); //despite calling a function to change the state of add in values it remains the same 
              return (
                <Row
                  key={index}
                  style={{
                    gridTemplateColumns: "22% 25% 2% 25% 25% 21%",
                    display: "grid",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>
                    {data.name}
                  </p>
                  <div>
                    <CompleteButton //CompleteButton is a styled div
                      isAdd={values[index]?.add} 
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.changeFalse(index) //function call
                      }}
                    >
                    </CompleteButton>
                  </div>
```

And this is what the changeFalse function looks like:

```
    changeFalse(index) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      values: {
        ...prevState.values,
        [prevState.values[index].add]: !prevState.values[index].add,
      },
    }));
  }
```

No matter how many times I click the button, it does not update and sti;; remains "false" and I'm not sure why

Comment: can you try passing index as the argument to arrow function like this onClick={(index) => { this.changeFalse(index) //function call }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are setting the `EDITABLE_FINANCIALS` values on to state but you are not rendering them from state, you are rendering the raw `EDITABLE_FINANCIALS`.

Try `this.state.values.map(...)` instead of mapping `EDITABLE_FINANCIALS`.

Secondly, in your handler `changeFalse`, you are setting `values` to be an object.

What you want to do instead is something like this:

```
 toggleAdd(index) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
    const newValues = [...values]
     newValues[index].add = !newValues[index].add

     return { values: newValues }
    });
  }
```

Comment: For my understanding, did I need to set values as an array instead of an object?

Comment: @user12414630 yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that because you're `onClick` is on `CompleteButton` which is a `styled.div` try putting the `onClick` to the `div` above `CompleteButton`.

Comment: The function is being called, I added a console.log to confirm

Comment: How about trying to force update it? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate)

Comment: Do you have an example of how to use forceUpdate here? I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined` if I keep my code same as posted except change `this.setState` to `this.forceUpdate` in the second line of the `changeFalse` function

Comment: I wonder why you're key is `[prevState.values[index].add]` isn't `prevState.values[index].add` enough? I'm sorry I can only code using hooks. I have only used `forceUpdate` using hooks.