# Manually refresh or re-render component onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way in React to just refresh a component not the window but the component itself? This is so I can re-trigger a react-query. I know I can use `useEffect()` but what would be the way to do it?

So I know I could do, something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
     setFetchData(result);
}, [result]);
```

This would trigger the component to re-render when `result` changes. But how can you have a button that would manually refresh the component or re-render it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you force a React component to rerender without calling setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626030/can-you-force-a-react-component-to-rerender-without-calling-setstate)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to refresh the component just to re-trigger a query from `react-query`, you'd better use `refetch` function provided by `useQuery` hook.

```
const { data, refetch, ... } = useQuery(...);

return (
  <>
    {(data?.yourQuery?.results || []).map(result => ...)}
    <button onClick={refetch}>Refetch!</button>
  </>
)
```

If there are some changes of `data` after calling `refetch`, the component will be automatically rerendered.

Comment: Is there a way though to show the loading state as apposed to the 'Updating' state

Comment: Refetch function does refetch query but how could I refresh the component based on that?

Comment: `useQuery` also provides `isLoading` and `isRefetching` boolean states, so you can conditionally render loading components using them. Referring to this [docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery) will help you understand how this hook works.

Comment: After you `refetch` the query, there will be (or not, sometimes...) updates of `data`. Then you show results of the query inside your component using `data`. Because `data` is updated, so is the component. It will be re-rendered automatically.

Comment: I have created an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-jfq8ve?file=index.tsx I want it so the query goes into the loading state not updating state when the button is clicked

Comment: Do you mean in that example you want to render “Loading data…” without list of data when the query is being re-triggered?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Could you update the stackblitz example?

Comment: Sorry for being late.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-j87pub?file=index.tsx
I think this might help you.

Comment: Can you please add as answer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825205/manually-refresh-react-query-onclick-with-react/69825333#69825333

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
const [reload, setReload] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
     // Add your code here
}, [reload]);

return (
 <button onClick={() => setReload(!reload)} >Reload</button>
);
```

And anytime you click the button it will execute the code inside the useEffect and update the component.