# Manually triggering useQuery from useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

My app has a modal with a few buttons. When the buttons are clicked, calls are made to the server, which work as expected. However, the screen does not refresh with the changes and I can't figure out how to make it work. I think I need to update the data, which will cause the components to render again, which is why I'm trying to use `refetch`. FYI - I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825205/manually-refresh-react-query-onclick-with-react), which helps a lot, but I'm not sure what's wrong with my implementation.

```
...
import { GetData } from '../../Api/GetData';
...

export const Timeline = ({props}) => {
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(true)

  const {isLoading, isSuccess, data, refetch} = useQuery("key",
    GetData({name: props.name, period: props.period}), {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    enabled: false
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if(refresh) {
      setRefresh(false)
      refetch()
    }
  }, [refresh, refetch]) // refresh is set to true by child components

  if(isLoading) ...
}
```

```
export const GetData = async (params) => {
  const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_ESPO_BASE_URL
  const url = "https://..."
  
  const headers = {"X-Api-Key": process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}

  const response = await fetch(url, {method: "GET", headers: headers})
  return response.json()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I can see, your query depends on `props.name` and `props.period` so you might want to add them to the `queryKey` array as dependencies. That way, whenever one of those values change, your query will automatically update. You will need to set `enabled` to `true` though.

Comment: It needs to be manually triggered, which is why the props are not part of the key. I'll remove all of that since it is not part of the question.

Comment: Have you checked on react query's dev tools? maybe you can get a hint of what's happening.

Comment: By the way, are you using react-query v4? If so, all keys need to be arrays since it seems react-query no longer automatically convert them to arrays (`['key']`).

Comment: I am using 3.39.x. Thanks for the pointer because I was about to upgrade to 4.x. Regarding your other question, I am not sure what is happening. I think this is based on my misunderstanding of how components are rendered. I'll do some more digging. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're executing `GetData` when you set up `useQuery` rather than passing in a function.  You can improve this by changing your `useQuery` call to something like

```
const {isLoading, isSuccess, data, refetch} = useQuery("key",
    () => GetData({name: props.name, period: props.period}), {
    staleTime: Infinity,
    enabled: false
  })
```

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. Would you recommend a different way to run the query other than using refetch?