# How to programmatically update the value of React datetime slider picker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I'm using the [React datetime slider picker](https://github.com/Porinn/react-datetime-slider-picker) and I don't know how to update its value e.g. when pressing a button.

I render the widget like this:

```
  <RDSPwidget
    enableSecond={true}
  />
```

where my `RDSPwidget` is defined as follows:

```
import Calendar from 'react-datetime-slider-picker/dist/Calendar';
import TimePicker from 'react-datetime-slider-picker/dist/TimePicker';
import { Tabs, Tab, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import Language from 'react-datetime-slider-picker/public/Language';

class RDSPwidget extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.state = {
        tab: 0,
        date: {year: 2000, month: 1, date: 1},
        time: {hour: 1, minute: 1, second: 1},
        counter: 1
      };
  
      this.onTabChange = this.onTabChange.bind(this);
      this.onValueChange = this.onValueChange.bind(this);
      this.updateValue = this.updateValue.bind(this);
    }
  
    onTabChange(value) {
      this.setState({ tab: value });
    }
  
    onValueChange(isDate, value) {
      let date = this.state.date,
        time = this.state.time;
      if (isDate) {
        date = {
          year: value.year,
          month: value.month,
          date: value.date
        };
        this.setState({ date: date });
      } else {
        time = value;
        this.setState({ time: time });
      }
    }

    updateValue() {
      this.setState({ date: {year: 2020, month: 10, date: 10} });
    }
    
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      let that = this;
      this.setState({ date: nextProps.value.date, time: nextProps.value.time });
      let tab = this.state.tab;
      this.setState({ tab: 1-tab });
      setTimeout(function() {
        that.setState({ tab: tab });
      }, 0);
    }
  
    render() {  
  
      const language = (this.props.language === 'ko') ? Language['ko'] : Language['en'];
  
      return (
        <div className='picker'>
          <div className='picker-tab'>
            <Tabs
              value={this.state.tab}
              onChange={(event, value) => this.onTabChange(value)}
              fullWidth
              textColor='inherit'
              classes={{ indicator: 'picker-tab-indicator' }}
            >
              <Tab 
                label={language.date} 
                icon={<Today />} 
                classes={{ selected: 'selected' }} 
              />
              <Tab 
                label={language.time} 
                icon={<AccessTime />} 
                classes={{ selected: 'selected' }} 
              />
            </Tabs>
          </div>
          <div className='picker-form'>
            {(this.state.tab === 0) ?
              <Calendar
                language={this.props.language}
                defaultValue={this.state.date}
                onChange={(date) => this.onValueChange(true, date)}
              /> :
              <TimePicker
                language={this.props.language}
                enableSecond={this.props.enableSecond}
                defaultValue={this.state.time}
                onChange={(time) => this.onValueChange(false, time)}
              />}
          </div>
          <button onClick={this.updateValue}>Update</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

I wrote this code a long time ago and I don't remember why I use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` (I'm not fluent with React).

Please how to programmatically change the date displayed by the widget?

---

## EDIT

It seems that the problem is related to this conditional component:

```
          <div className='picker-form'>
            {(this.state.tab === 0) ?
              <Calendar
                language={this.props.language}
                defaultValue={this.state.date}
                onChange={(date) => this.onValueChange(true, date)}
              /> :
              <TimePicker
                language={this.props.language}
                enableSecond={this.props.enableSecond}
                defaultValue={this.state.time}
                onChange={(time) => this.onValueChange(false, time)}
              />}
          </div>
```

Indeed, when I am on the `Calendar` tab and press the button, nothing happens. But if I switch to the `TimePicker` tab and go back to the `Calendar` tab, then the updated date appears.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution: I had to force a re-rendering.

First, I changed my widget as follows, but this has no importance I think:

```
      <div className='picker'>
        <div className='picker-tab'>
          <TabContext value={this.state.tab}>
            <AppBar position="static">
              <TabList
                onChange={(event, value) => this.onTabChange(value)}
              >
                <Tab 
                  value={0}
                  label={language.date} 
                  icon={<Today />} 
                  classes={{ selected: 'selected' }} 
                />
                <Tab 
                  value={1}
                  label={language.time} 
                  icon={<AccessTime />} 
                  classes={{ selected: 'selected' }} 
                />
              </TabList>
            </AppBar>
            <TabPanel value={0}>
              <div className='picker-form'>
                <Calendar
                  key={this.state.calendarKey}
                  language={this.props.language}
                  defaultValue={this.state.date}
                  onChange={(date) => this.onValueChange(true, date)}
                />
              </div>            
            </TabPanel>
            <TabPanel value={1}>
              <div className='picker-form'>
                <TimePicker
                  key={this.state.timepickerKey}
                  language={this.props.language}
                  enableSecond={this.props.enableSecond}
                  defaultValue={this.state.time}
                  onChange={(time) => this.onValueChange(false, time)}
                />
              </div>          
            </TabPanel>
          </TabContext>
        </div>
      </div>
```

As you can see, I use the `key` prop for the `Calendar` and the `Timepicker`. That's because I follow the way given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47974562) to force the re-rendering. I tried `forceUpdate` and this had no effect.

Then here is the code triggered by the button click:

```js
      this.setState({
        date: {year: 2020, month: 10, date: 10},
        time: {hour: 1, minute: 1, second: 1}
      });
      let calendarKey = this.state.calendarKey;
      let timepickerKey = this.state.timepickerKey;
      let that = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        that.setState({ 
          calendarKey: calendarKey + 1,
          timepickerKey: timepickerKey + 1
        });
      }, 0);
```